# SQL Server 2005 Express: Cannot install database diagram support objects

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2005

I'm refering to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/110499/sql-server-2005-cannot-install-database-diagram-support-objects) question where the final solution was `When I finally realized this, and connected via VPN to the corporate network, everything worked like a charm.`

Now in same situation I'm in corporate domain using VPN, still I'm not able to run the given script. 
I'm getting this error

```
Msg 15404, Level 16, State 19, Line 1
Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'DomainName\username', error code 0x5.
```

Comment: is it a single or multiple domain environment? is your server is the same domain as the group/user its trying to get information about?

Comment: @Nick, I don't understand much about networking so don't know what Multiple Domain Environment means. But I'm connected to two networks. One for accessing internet and second for connecting to my corporate domain via VPN. I'm using Windows 7

Comment: is everything using the same domain name?

Comment: Now I got to know from my colleague that I'm not logged in to domain but using VPN I'm able to access network of my corporate domain.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 0x5 is access denied.  For some reason the machine (or the account which is running the SQL Server) is being denied access to the active directory database.

Why are you trying to use the native database diagrams?  They pretty much suck.  Of the possible diagramming tools they are pretty much the worst.  Try Visio instead.

Comment: They suck so much you've gotta go out of your way to install them. Visio = much better - if you have a copy of visio that is

Comment: True that. I forgot that not everyone has MSDN licenses which include Office.

Comment: Thanks I've visio. But many times I change the database columns directly in actual DB and just remove/add table to diagram in Management studio makes the changes (addition/deletion of column in a table). So both diagram and actual DB schema remains in sync. That is why I use Mgt studio for diagramming.

Comment: Visio can update its diagram.  You just have to tell it to update from the database.  It is an extra step.  IMO the extra step is worth it compared to the flexibility and features that Visio gives you.

Comment: My company is a Microsoft Partner and it provides us (programmers) facility to use all the Microsoft applications. I will give Visio a try.